# react-native passing props AND navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

In a react-native child-component, I need to read both  parent-props and navigation.

I use this code in parent to pass DIC-props to child, which works just fine:

```
...
<Stack.Screen name="SignIn>
     {(props) => <SignIn {...props} DIC={DIC} />}
</Stack.Screen>
...
```

In Child comp. I get that prop (DIC) like this, so far all fine:

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
  const { DIC } = props
...
```

}

But in Child I need now to get navigation from props too, but this does not work (navigation appears as an empty object)

```
const SignIn = (props, {navigation}) => {
  const { DIC } = props
...
```

Can someone see what am I doing wrong? How can I get both specific props AND navigation? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you using Typescript so that you can better understand what is happening under the hood. Anyway, as for your question, this should work for you:

```
const SignIn = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const DIC = route.params.DIC
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get navigation like this:

`const { DIC, navigation } = props;`

navigation comes within props.